# How to send checkbox state through form in a table

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, html-table

Below form contains a table with checkboxes as a input type
when I do a var_dump of _POST the values of each check box doesn't come through

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3" name="details" >
        <div id="table_container">   
        <table class="z">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Street Num</th>
                    <th>Street Name</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Zip</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    ?>  
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="<?echo $row['UUID'];?>">    
                        </td>
                        <td><?echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['street_num'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['street_name'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['city'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['state'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['zip'];?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['phone'];?></td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <?                  
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="4">
            <input type="submit" value="Place On Hold">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think what you want to do is this though. If I understand it correctly.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="UUID[]" value="<?echo $row['UUID'];?>">
```

Now when you post the page you will have an array called UUID in the POST with each UUID selected.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question originally. Updated answer with how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is your checkbox:
`<input type="checkbox" name="uid" value="some_value">`

you can use below code to check whether this checkbox is checked or not:

```
 <?php
  echo (isset($_POST['uid'])?$_POST['uid']:'');
 ?>
```

`isset($_POST['uid'])` will check whether its checked or not, and therefore `$_POST['uid']` will return its value if checked.

Comment: But if there is more than one selected he will not get all of them... thus the brackets are necessary `name="uid[]"`

Comment: the while loop doesn't loop over a text string. you need the form itself to post an array, not text... your method would cause `$_POST['uid']` to get replaced by the last checkbox selected

Comment: Its inside the loop so every time check box of name `uid[]` will be created right? so why not give every checkbox a different name. like
using this : `name="uid[$i]"`

Comment: you could do that to, but then it would only make sense if it was a radio type select. where there's a chance the uid could have more than one option... he was not looking for that... `<input type="radio" name="UUID[<?echo $row['UUID'];?>]" value="one"><input type="radio" name="UUID[<?echo $row['UUID'];?>]" value="two"><input type="radio" name="UUID[<?echo $row['UUID'];?>]" value="three">`

Comment: okay. got it. but to check whether its checked or not he might use `isset($_POST['uid[]'])` ? right?

Comment: no... he would do `foreach($_POST['uid'])` PHP will cause the `name='uid[]'` to turn into an array just called 'uid' with each element being the value of the UUID

Comment: but suppose if none is checked then there will be error stating `Undefined Index 'uid'`

Comment: so? just wrap it in an `if (isset($_POST['uid']) && sizeof($_POST['uid']))` but honestly in production with error_reporting off it won't complain at all... but it would be 'sloppy'